# Spring Batch or Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I need to build a pipeline system for setting up different types of data. For example, when a customer signs up, the first time the user logs in, i need to setup some sample data, sample reports. The data is not fully static as it will add some time sensitive stuff, Like tasks that can expire in 30 days, 10 days.

In order to make this happen, we already have some REST services that can insert the data I need to add for the customer. What I was wondering is that for the orchestration, is spring batch the right way or spring integration the right way ?

Comment: why spring Integration?

Answer (score 0):

Spring integration all the way. You could model it in batch but you're not really doing batch processing. You're simply doing repeated tasks per user based on a given signal (first login). I would use integration first. You can always integrate batch later if needs be but integration is a shorter learning curve and I feel suits your needs better.